# Выбор между NavigadionDrawer и BottomNavigation

Tags: java, android, android-navigation-drawer, bottom-navigation-view

В каком случае при создании прилжения лучше выбрать для навигации NavigadionDrawer, а в каком BottomNavigation? Какой вариант лучше для масштабируемости приложения и его вариантов использования и будет более понятен и приятен для пользователя?

Comment: О том, когда какой паттерн навигации (из восьми известных) лучше использовать [написано в гайдлайнах](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigation.html#navigation-patterns), кроме того по BottomNavigation [написано отдельно на его странице](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-usage) с множеством примеров удачной и неудачной практики использования.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данный ответ на вопрос является моим рассуждением и не может быть принят как истина.

**Bottom Navigation:**

Плюсы:

- Последнее время большинство крупных приложений переходит с бокового `NavigationDrawer` на нижний боттом. У меня есть предположение, что это связано с увеличением диагонали экранов. дотянуться в верхний левый угол на текущих экранах одной рукой уже не реально. Боттом навигашейн облегчает задачу взаимодействия с навигацией по приложению. Дотянуться до нужного пункта намного легче
- Минимализм. Пользователь сразу видит основной функционал(Если у вас кучу элементов навигации, то подумайте, может у вас проблемы с UX)
- Быстрое взаимодействие. Вся навигация сразу на виду.

Минусы:

- Занимает место внизу, чем уменьшает пространство для потребления информации.
- Имеет ограничение в 5 элементов по всем гайдлайнам. Так что если у вас много элементов, вам придется один элемент навигейшна превратить в подобие NavigationDrawer.

**NavigationDrawer:**

Плюсы:

- Можно запихнуть туда кучу всего.
- Не занимает места на экране пока не вызовешь.

Минусы:

- Неудобно тянуться (свайпать)
- До каждого пункта меню тяжело тянуться

**Что бы я выбрал?** Ответ - `Bottom Navigation`.

Почему? Мне нравятся все его плюсы.

Очень часто `NavigationDrawer` превращается в свалку всего что можно.

**Что делать с минусами боттом навигейшна?**

Ну первый минус решается следующим образом: если пользователь начинает скролить вниз, то скрывать боттом навигейшн и при скролле вверх снова показывать.

Надеюсь понятно, что если вся информация вкладки помещается сразу на экране, то скролл невозможен и боттом прятать не надо.

Второй минус - думайте надо своим UX. Если всё хорошо продумано, такой проблемы тупо не возникнет.